# sql server trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sql server trigger help - same table update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573352/sql-server-trigger-help-same-table-update)

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008. I have two tables credit and invoice.

The code for the credit table:

```
create table CREDIT(
CREDIT_ID numeric(5) PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
CREDIT_STATUS varchar (25))
```

The code for the invoice table:

```
create table INVOICE(
INVOICE_ID numeric(5) PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
CREDIT_ID numeric(5) not null,
INVOICE_STATUS varchar(25) not null,
FOREIGN KEY (CREDIT_ID) REFERENCES CREDIT(CREDIT_ID))
```

The insert statement(s) for credit:

```
 insert into credit
 values ('open')
```

I want to create a trigger - when an insert statement is entered on the invoice table - if the invoice_status is 'pending' - the credit_status remains 'open'. If the invoice_status is 'overdue' - the credit_status is updated (triggered) to 'blocked'.

The problem I'm having (i think) is based on the primary key identifiers - it doesn't know which one to update.

The trigger code I have so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[test] on [dbo].[invoice]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @invoice_status varchar(25)
select @invoice_status = (select invoice_status from  inserted    WHERE                 invoice_status = 'overdue')
insert into credit (credit_status) values ('Blocked')

select @invoice_status = (select invoice_status from inserted WHERE invoice_status = 'pending')
insert into credit (credit_status) values ('Open')  

END
GO
```

Sorry for any confusion!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: This trigger looks like it's only geared to handle one row - you'll need to join to `inserted`, use an `in` or `exists` statement, or loop through the rows manually (not recommended!)

It also looks like you're trying to insert rows into credit from the trigger - surely you want to be updating rows in the `INVOICE` table instead?

Comment: You should probably delete this question now you created a duplicate of it (the other thread has more reponses).