# sql server trigger help - same table update

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I posted a similar question earlier - but can't seem to get a long enough response! Sorry if I shouldn't be posting again!

This is using SQL Server 2008. I have a table called invoice;

```
create table INVOICE(
INVOICE_ID numeric(5) PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
INVOICE_STATUS varchar(25) not null,
TRADER_STATUS varchar (25))
```

I want to create a trigger when an insert is entered; and the invoice_status = 'pending' - the trader_status is updated (triggered) to 'open'. When an insert is entered; and the invoice_status = 'overdue' - the trader_status is updated (triggered) to 'blocked'.

The trigger code I have;

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[test] on [dbo].[invoice]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @invoice_status varchar(25)
select @invoice_status = (select invoice_status from  inserted WHERE invoice_status = 'PENDING')
insert into invoice (trader_status) values ('OPEN')

select @invoice_status = (select invoice_status from  inserted WHERE invoice_status = 'OVERDUE')
insert into invoice (trader_status) values ('BLOCKED')

 END
 GO
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would make the trigger FOR INSERT only for starters...

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations.  Designing a trigger on the assumption that they will always contain exactly one row is generally a bad plan.  If you are absolutely certain there will never be more than one row then please add a check for the number of rows and use `RaIsError` to explicitly inform those who come along later that they have attempted to execute an unacceptable statement.  (`if ( select Count(*) from inserted ) > 1 RaIsError( 'FooTable_Insert: No more than one row may be processed.', 25, 42 ) with log`)

Answer (score 1):

```
create trigger [dbo].[test] on [dbo].[invoice]
for insert
as
begin

update Invoice
  set Trader_Status = 'OPEN'
  where Invoice_Id in ( select Invoice_Id from inserted where Invoice_Status = 'PENDING' )

update Invoice
  set Trader_Status = 'BLOCKED'
  where Invoice_Id in ( select Invoice_Id from inserted where Invoice_Status = 'OVERDUE' )

end
```

Note that this will handle more than one row being inserted by a single statement.